# Rails serving old pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails is serving an old version of my website's home page when I turn caching on When I turn it off, Rails serves the right version of the page. I have the following configuration in my production.rb file:

```
# Code is not reloaded between requests
config.cache_classes = true
config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=3600"

# Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

# Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
config.serve_static_assets = true

# Compress JavaScripts and CSS
config.assets.compress = true
config.assets.css_compressor = :yui
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglify

# Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
config.assets.compile = true

# Generate digests for assets URLs
config.assets.digest = true
```

Does anybody know what's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails is serving a cached version of your page, as you said.

You need to expire those cached pages; try `rake tmp:cache:clear`.

Comment: It didn't work for me meagar. It's strange since the only page being served like this is the home page. The landing page.

Comment: Found it! I had an old "index.html" in the public folder. I removed that and ran rake tmp:cache:clear. Thanks!